# Restricted cubic spline plot of logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, spline, cubic-spline

I am having trouble with getting the Y-axis to display the correct odds ratio values when plotting a logistic regression with restricted cubic splines using the Predict() function. The values seem very low and do not reflect other analysis I have done previously on the same dataset. So I am just wondering what I have done in the code shown below. I am not sure how I can produce a working example online as it is quite a large dataframe I am dealing with. Can anyone help?

**Variables in dataframe used in the model:**

> **admitted**: factor w/ 2 levels "Not_admitted", "Admitted"
>
> **body_mass_index**: num [1:7630] 21.5 24.4 26.4 41.8 27.7 ...

**Code:**

```
library(Hmisc)
library(survival)
library(rms)
library(ggplot2)

ddist <- datadist(df)
options(datadist='ddist')

model <- lrm(admitted ~ rcs(body_mass_index, 4), data=df)

ggplot(Predict(model, fun=exp), ylab="Odds ratio")
```

**Plot:**

[Spline plot - click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZAwf.png)

Comment: Any chance you could include sample data that also duplicated the problem?

Comment: Here is a link to a csv that will replicate the issue I am having. 

https://easyupload.io/gu54ey